# null java list to scala Buffer

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

Imagine I have a java list

```
val javaList: java.util.List[String] = null
```

If I wanted to use it as scala collection, let's say Buffer, I would simply add the following import (as described many times before)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

The problem is that I have to check if the list is different from null. This will not work:

```
javaList foreach println          //throws java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is there a simple way to convert java list to scala collection in such a way, that null is converted to Buffer.empty? Something similar to Option factory:

```
Option(null)                      //> res0: Option[Null] = None
asScalaBuffer(javaList)           // I wish this to be ArrayBuffer()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just map it over and work with Option

```
Option(javaList).map(asScalaBuffer).getOrElse(ArrayBuffer.empty)
```

**Update**

If you still want a factory for `null` arrays/lists, then you can simulate it by a "constructor method" (basing on Rex Kerr's answer):

```
def ArrayBuffer[T](jl: JavaList[T]) = if (jl == null) ArrayBuffer.empty[T] else asScalaBuffer(jl)
```

and then use `ArrayBuffer(null.asInstanceOf[JavaList[String])` it looks just like `Option.apply`:

```
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
```

Comment: That is what I am doing so far. Thought there is an easier way

Comment: @rarry and what's hard in this method?

Comment: Nothing. I think your answer is ok. I'll wait a little bit longer to make sure that the factory doesn't exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can always define your own:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
def safeScala[A](xs: java.util.List[A]) = {
  if (xs == null) collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[A]()
  else xs.asScala
}
```